Launch new terminal window via hotkey MacOS
Terminal keymap on MacOS
I was searching for hours to figure out a simple way to create a hotkey shortcut to launch a new terminal window. Posting this here in case anyone else was wondering how to do it.
Download skhd (Simple hotkey daemon for macOS).
skhd github
  brew install koekeishiya/formulae/skhd
  skhd --start-service

Now that you have the daemon installed/running create a AppleScript file openwez.scpt. This file will be used by skhd to create the keymap.
set appName to "WezTerm"

if application appName is running then
  Do Shell Script "/Applications/WezTerm.app/Contents/MacOS/wezterm-gui"
else
  tell application appName to activate
end if

Now create the file .skhdrc, that calls the script:
cmd - return: osascript ~/Scripts/openwez.scpt

run skhd --reload now the keymap should work.
credit: wezterm github issues page

Welcome to SuperUser. You're encouraged to answer your own question in cases like this, but you need to make the answer a real answer post in reply to your question post, so that you can click the checkmark to accept your own answer as the official answer, so the question gets marked as resolved. Don't put the answer text inside the body of the question post; that's not how this site works.
